# Simple Interfagment Communication in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to perform a onclick activity on one fragment which is reflected in the textview of another fragment in same activity

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Communicator{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FragmentManager FM=getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment2 f2=(Fragment2) FM.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changeText(data);

    }


}
```

**Fragment1.java**

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    Button btn;
    Communicator comm;
    int counter=0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        // Point interface to main activity
        comm=(Communicator) getActivity();
        btn=(Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1_id);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        counter++;
        comm.respond("Button is clicked"+counter+"times");
    }

}
```

**Fragment2.java**

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment{

    TextView TV;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container,false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        TV=(TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1_id);
    }


    public void changeText(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TV.setText(data);
    }

}
```

**Communicator.java**

```
public interface Communicator {

    void respond(String data);
}
```

**Log**::

```
12-25 18:33:07.961: E/AndroidRuntime(454): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.simplestdynamicfragment2.Fragment1
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.example.simplestdynamicfragment2.MainActivity.respond(MainActivity.java:22)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.example.simplestdynamicfragment2.Fragment1.onClick(Fragment1.java:43)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-25 18:33:07.996: E/AndroidRuntime(454):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what is line 22 in main activity?

Comment: Fragment2 f2=(Fragment2) FM.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);

Comment: can you check the import of Fragment class in Fragment2, is it a `android.app.fragment` or `android.support.v4.fragment`. if it is the first one then you cant cast older version fragment to newer class.

Comment: I checked, it is android.support.v4.fragment

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit different approach. You can do something like this :

In your `activity` create a `public method` :

```
public void SOME_METHOD_NAME()
{
 //Write code to change text in second fragment
 FragmentManager FM=getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment2 f2=(Fragment2) FM.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changeText(data);
}
```

Now in your first `fragment` call this `method` like this :

```
OnClick()
{
  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).SOME_METHOD_NAME();
}
```

And in your second `fragment` code should be same as yours :

```
 public void changeText(String data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TV.setText(data);
    }
```

I haven't tested this code as I wrote this directly here. But It should work perfectly.